# How to let Python recognize both lower and uppercase for the input?

Tags: python

I am doing my homework now and want to make python recognize both lower and uppercase for the input. Here is the script:

```
print("Welcome to the student checker!")

student_lists={"Mary A","Tony Z","Sophie L","Zoe J","Joey M","Connie O","Olivia L","Mark Z","Donny M"}

while True:

    name=input("Please give me the name of a student (enter 'q' to quit):")

    if name in student_lists:
        print("Yes, that student is enrolled in the class!")

    else:
        print("No, that student is not in the class.")

    if name=="q":
        break

print("Goodbye!")
```

Please let me know how to fix it. Much appreciated!!

Comment: I don't understand, in which step you need to recognize the letter case? and what to do with that ?

Comment: You could convert the input and all elements in the list to lower case bevor comparison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Making a copy of the student_list list and parsing all names as lowercase.
student_list_lowercase = []
for item in student_list:
    student_list_lowercase.append(item.lower())

name=input("Please give me the name of a student (enter 'q' to quit):")

#Testing that the lowercase version of the student's name is present in the newly created list.
if name.lower() in student_lists_lowercase():
    print("Yes, that student is enrolled in the class!")

else:
    print("No, that student is not in the class.")

if name=="q":
    break
```

Comment: `lower()` is *almost* the right answer, but will not behave correctly with various internationalized strings. `str.casefold()` is what you probably should be using (see Veedrac's answer in the proposed duplicate).

Comment: Thanks! str.casefold() works as well! Perfect!! :)

Answer (score 0):

First, convert all elements in the `student_lists` set to lowercase letters:

```
student_lists = {name.lower() for name in student_lists}
```

and then instead of

```
if name in student_lists:
```

use

```
if name.lower() in student_lists:
```

to have all letters lowercase in the comparison.

Comment: `lower()` is *almost* the right answer, but will not behave correctly with various internationalized strings. `str.casefold()` is what you probably should be using (see Veedrac's answer in the proposed duplicate).

Comment: Thank you guys!! i made all the names lowercases in student_lists and used the lower(), which is working now!!

Comment: @LynS, the preferred form of "thank you" in StackOverflow is voting up the answer.